# Set AddThis Module to work on all Pages

Tags: php, magento, module, addthis

I've installed AddThis Module for Magento.

But this extension works only on product pages. Do you know how can I set sharing buttons to appear on all pages?
I've searched on all the source code but didn't figured out where is set to appear only on Product Pages.

So I guess the problem might be from app/design/frontend/default/default/template/addthis/sharingtool/share.phtml
In this page is loaded some javascript code.
Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solutions:

**1. My solution:**

Go to: app/code/community/AddThis/SharingTool/Model/Observer.php

Change this:

```
  if ($block->getNameInLayout()=='product_review_list.count') {
```

To this:

```
  if (strstr($block->getNameInLayout(),'search')) {
```

(So addthis share buttons will appear on all pages that contain the search option)

**2**.I also emailed addthis official support and the answer was:

> You can add Share buttons in any CMS or .phtml files.

**2.1 For cms pages you can use**

```
{{block type="sharingtool/share" name="addthis_sharetool"}}
```

**2.2 In any phtml files you can use**

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sharingtool/share')->setBlockId('addthis_sharetool')->toHtml();
?>
```

**Here is the support document.**
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381234-addthis-for-magento